# Centre a fragment or wrap its content in a ScrollView depending on its content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a layout hierarchy which includes some content at the top of a `ScrollView` and a nested fragment (using a `FragmentContainerView`) below that content.

What I want is for a fragment to either fill the space or exceed it, depending on the content. I originally expected setting the child fragment's layout to `match_parent` and `wrap_content` respectively would work, but the content won't scroll at all.

Currently my layout is as follows:

*Parent fragment*

```xml
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/top_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_content_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_content" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

*Child fragment 1*

```xml
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

*Child fragment 2*

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    ...
</FrameLayout>
```

This setup either shows the content in *Child fragment 1* centered or the content in *Child fragment 2* wrapping its content from the top, which is exactly what I want. However this then prevents the layout from scrolling at all, clearly because the `FragmentContainerView` has a limited height.

Is there a clean solution for this whilst preserving scrolling or another solution that would achieve the same (XML-based, not programatically)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
      android:id="@+id/top_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
      android:id="@+id/main_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_content_margin"/>
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Child fragment 2

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  ...
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I thought this was the answer but unfortunately it still refuses to scroll!

Comment: Try my edit , if it's not what you want , please describe more detail

Comment: Unfortunately not, what I want is to have different child fragments where, if their height it `match_parent` then they fill the container, but if their height is `wrap_content` they wrap their content. However trying this like in my question causes the `wrap_content` child to not scroll, it's just fixed in place.

Comment: What's inside your top_content. I set it's height 100dp then it worked

Comment: Just a couple of buttons, the container is `wrap_content`. Strange that a fixed height would work, I'll try it!